# docker container ipv6 configuration not working

Tags: docker, docker-engine

I've setup a CoreOs host with a public routable /64 ipv6 Subnet.
From within the host i have a global ipv6 address which is working fine but i can't get access to ipv6 hosts from within any docker container.

These are my current settings to my docker deamon:

```
DOCKER_OPTS=--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --ipv6 --fixed-cidr-v6='2a03:4000:6:e0d0::/64'
```

Adding `--ip-forward=false` or the google ipv6 DNS servers doesn't help either

Only if I add `--net=host` it works so I think I'm missing a fundamental network configuration part.

ifconfig from within an ubuntu:latest docker container shows this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a03:4000:6:e0d0:0:242:ac11:2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1565 (1.5 KB)  TX bytes:676 (676.0 B)
```

What special configuration do i need to do to get this working?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember exactly how I solved this but if I remember correctly i ended up using some workaround like this: https://github.com/DanielAdolfsson/ndppd/ to get it working

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the solution for myself. I documented everything in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55519105/787824