# How do I connect to to hosts network from within a docker container?

Tags: docker, networking, ipv6

I have two physical servers connected to each other in a LAN. Server A runs docker with a ubuntu container. Server B runs a MySQL-database (without any docker stuff).

Now I need to access the MySQL-Database on Server B from within a docker-container on Server A.

Server B only has an ipv6-address.

When I run `ping6 <ipv6_server_b>` on Host A it works. The same command from within the docker-container on Host A gives me a `unknown host`.

I think I need to create a docker bridge to the ipv6-subnet of Server B. All my efforts led to the same `unknown host` error. And I don't want to use `--network=host`.

The public internet is connected on hosts interface `ens16` while Server B is in a local security zone connected on interface `ens17`

### Detailed Description

I enabled ipv6 in docker options like this:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --ipv6 --fixed-cidr-v6=2001:db8:1::/64 "
```

**1. I tried to create a bridge network to the ipv6 subnet of the security zone**

```
docker network create --driver bridge --ipv6 --subnet=fcfc:0:0:1::/64 db-link
```

**2. This is the command I use to start the container and assign the network**

`docker run -it --network=db-link nicolaka/netshoot`

(nicolaka/netshoot contains a lot of useful diagnostic stuff)

**3. Trying to ping the Server B address from in the container:**

```
ping6 fcfc::1:24fc:25ff:fe25:c903
PING fcfc::1:24fc:25ff:fe25:c903(fcfc::1:24fc:25ff:fe25:c903) 56 data bytes
From fcfc:0:0:1::2: icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fcfc:0:0:1::2: icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From fcfc:0:0:1::2: icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.18.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra02s19-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.18.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=0.787 ms
64 bytes from fra02s19-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.18.14): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=0.631 ms
```

**4. This is the output of the `ip`-commands in the container**

```
ip -6 route show
fcfc:0:0:1::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fcfc:0:0:1::1 dev eth0 metric 1024 pref medium

ip route show
default via 172.21.0.1 dev eth0
172.21.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.2
```

**5. I tried to create a `macvlan` network**

```
docker network create --driver macvlan --ipv6 --subnet=fcfc:0:0:1::/64 -o parent=ens17 db-link
```

Now I can ping the Server B's IP `fcfc::1:24fc:25ff:fe25:c903` but as the macvlan limits access to the distinct interface, I cant connect to public internet.

**6. Conclusion**

- The bridge network is created but I don't get connection / route to the ipv6 submit of Server B – Why?
- The macvlan network enables the container to ping Server B but its impossible to reach the public internet.

Comment: Have you [enabled ipv6 in your docker configuration](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/)? Does your container have an ipv6 address?

Comment: Yes, and then I added a bridge like this `docker network create --driver bridge --ipv6 --subnet=fcfc::1:24fc:25ff:fe25:c903/80 db-link`. Pinging the Server B private IP `fcfc::1:24fc:25ff:fe25:c903` gives me `no route to host`

Comment: Could you move that information from the comment into your question, and also (a) the `docker run` command you're using to start the container and (b) the output of `ip addr` from inside the container?

Comment: I have updated the initial question. Thank you.

Comment: You are using Reserved IPv6 addressing that you are not allowed to use. There is no Private IPv6 address range. The `fc00::/7` block is ULA (_Unique_ Local Addressing), which is a very different concept from the IPv4 Private addressing. The first half of the block (`fc00::/8`) that you are using is Reserved for a global authority to assign. You can assign addressing in the second half of the block (`fd00::/8`), but you are required to pick the next 40 bits randomly. See _[RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin The IP `fcfc::1:24fc:25ff:fe25:c903` is assigned by the ISP. How do I calculate the corresponding subnet for the bridge to work? I'm afraid I don't have that much experience with ipv6.

Comment: ISPs should be assigning Global IPv6 addresses (`2000::/3`), not ULA addresses, and especially not Reserved addresses. You need a Global address to communicate across the public Internet. You can use a Private IPv4 address because you have NAT to translate that to a public IPv4 address, but IPv6 doesn't have NAT; you use IPv6 Global addressing to communicate on the public IPv6 Internet. IPv6 restores the IP end-to-end paradigm by having enough addresses that we do not need translation.

Comment: OK thank you. But I'm not sure if this affects my original problem because I CAN ping and use that IP in context of the host machine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together with the ISP we found a solution:

In `/etc/docker/daemon.json` we changed the subnet to:

```
{
"ipv6": true,
"fixed-cidr-v6": "fefe:1234::/80"
}
```

And then ran the following iptables-commands:

```
ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s fefe:1234::/80 -o ens16 -j MASQUERADE
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s fefe:1234::/80 -d fcfc::1/32 -o ens17 -j MASQUERADE
```

Now Im able to ping the ipv6 address from inside the container also with proper access to the public internet without usage of any custom bridge or macvlan networks.